# Unregister remoting type?

Tags: .net, wcf, remoting

I want to be able to connect to a function in an assemly from my desctop on different servers. Say I have function foo() in x.dll. I want to call foo on server 1, then call foo on server 2 etc. How can I do this? I prefer to do in remoting. If not possible then wcf.
I tried to do it with remoting. I first configured it on one server, and when I tried to configure on another server I got an exception.
Remoting configuration failed with the exception 'System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Attempt to redirect activation of type 'ControlServices.Controler, ControlServices' which is already redirected. at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfigHandler.RemotingConfigInfo.AddActivatedClientType(ActivatedClientTypeEntry entry) at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfiguration.RegisterActivatedClientType(ActivatedClientTypeEntry entry) at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfigHandler.RemotingConfigInfo.StoreRemoteAppEntries(RemotingXmlConfigFileData configData) at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfigHandler.ConfigureRemoting(RemotingXmlConfigFileData configData, Boolean ensureSecurity)'.
this is my code. I get error on RegisterActivatedClientType
 TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(); 
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, true);

```
    ActivatedClientTypeEntry remotetype = new ActivatedClientTypeEntry( 
        typeof(Controler), 
        "tcp://172.22.110.25:8086"); 
    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterActivatedClientType(remotetype); 

    Controler control = new Controler(); 
    string str = control.ServiceState("SchedulerServiceIT"); 




    channel.StopListening(null); 
    //RemotingServices.Disconnect(control); 
    ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(channel); 
    channel = null; 




     channel = new TcpChannel(); 
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, true); 

     remotetype = new ActivatedClientTypeEntry( 
        typeof(Controler), 
        "tcp://172.22.110.25:8086"); 
    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterActivatedClientType(remotetype); 

     control = new Controler(); 
     str = control.ServiceState("SchedulerServiceIT");
```

Comment: Please *at least* pay attention to formatting your question so that it's readable.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.
I create an application domain for each call on the remote object.
Like this article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28759/RemotingConfiguration-Unconfigure